# How to restore state of an Android View (UI)?

Tags: android

I'm trying to save state of my view in one activity and pass it to another activity using a Bundle. In the second activity I try to restore the view state using the bundle.

First Activity

```
private View CreateView() {
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
scrollView.addView(layout);         
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId(100);
btn.setText("Button Text");
btn.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());
layout.addView(btn);
return scrollView;
}
```

onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View v = CreateView();
setContentView(v);
```

Saving state

```
SparseArray<Parcelable> array = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
view.saveHierarchyState(array);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSparseParcelableArray("state", array);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity onCreate

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();        
View view = new View(this);
view.restoreHierarchyState(bundle.getSparseParcelableArray("state"));
setContentView(view.getRootView());   
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(100);
```

Everything works without an exception. However, I face two issues:
1. The view in second activity is blank. Though I've restored the saved state I can't see anything
2. Instance for the button (with id 100) in second activity is always null

While debugging I can see one of the values in the bundle having an id 100

Any help on what I seem to be doing wrong will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This strikes me as an odd thing to want to do. What's the reasoning?

Comment: @Dave - agreed it's an odd thing to do. regrettably i won't be able to discuss here the "why" part of it! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that it is not possible to restore a view in a different activity from which it was initially created (or rendered). Since View is not a serializable type, it can't be send in its entirety as well. At this point there doesn't seem to be any solution (I haven't explored option of modifying Android source code)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to create a *View* programatically and sending it to another activity? You could simply use the same layout in both activities and then only pass the data that backs the view. That too there would be more convenient ways than using a parcelable?

Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here? Maybe we can give you a better response then....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this in [onSavedInstanceState(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?

From the `Android` documentation:

> onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in
>   such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic
>   instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later
>   received in onCreate(Bundle)

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is called by Android when the activity is about to be pulled off the stack. However, I'm trying to pass the state from one view to another based on an application trigger. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I've taken with this is using the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    //save the state of the sign up views!
    Serializable page0fields = sign_in_page.getFields();
    outState.putSerializable("page0fields", page0fields);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //restore the state of the sign up views!
    sign_in_page.fillFields(
            savedInstanceState.getSerializable("page0fields")
            );
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

On the other hand, you seem to desire a much more automated approach to this. I don't believe you can pass around views arbitrarily, as they aren't serializable, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, Views aren't serializable. That's the reason why I'm using View.saveHierarchyState which returns a Bundle and which in turn is serializable